# Error while piping POST request using request library

Tags: node.js, sails.js, requestjs

I'm using `request` to communicate between two Sails applications. The concerned actions seem to get triggered but the form data shows `undefined`.

In app A:

**The concerned form**

```
<form action="/testreq" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="name" type="text"><br/>
    <input name="dp" type="file"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**The concerned controller**

```
  testreq: function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.param('name'));
    var r = request.post('http://localhost:9999/upload');
    req.pipe(r);
    return r.pipe(res);
  },
```

In app B:

**The concerned controller**

```
upload: function(req, res, next) {
    var name = req.param('name');
    console.log(name);// prints "undefined"
    return res.json({ message: 'Some message' });
}
```

While the `console.log` should print the name sent from the form, it outputs `undefined`. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've no experience with SailsJS so I might be completely off here, but worth a guess. If Sails uses body-parser or something like that (formidable etc?) to parse form data then it basically "consumes" the original stream so you can't pipe it anymore (as it originally does). In your app A you're re-piping the original request, so there might not *be* any form data in it anymore. There's plugins like [connect-restreamer](https://github.com/dominictarr/connect-restreamer) to solve this issue but it has its [problems](https://github.com/dominictarr/connect-restreamer/issues/8).